# I added firebase to my app for user profile., but now my app is causing all kind of errors, how to solve this (logcat added)?

Tags: java, android, firebase

This is the logcat. I dont know how to solve any of it, or even where the real problem is. Sometimes the logcat deletes itself, or doesnt show. It also shows different issues. But right now, my app isnt even showing in the emulator anymore.
The emulator i am using is 30.

```
     2020-08-31 13:34:14.962 466-566/? E/StorageUserConnection: Failed to bind to the ExternalStorageService for user 0
2020-08-31 13:36:15.450 466-566/? E/StorageUserConnection: Failed to bind to the ExternalStorageService for user 0
2020-08-31 13:36:43.633 466-566/? E/StorageUserConnection: Failed to bind to the ExternalStorageService for user 0
2020-08-31 13:37:06.197 2382-2932/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to get FIS auth token
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
        at kxk.b(PG:2)
        at kxk.a(PG:8)
        at rur.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at kgp.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:214)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:252)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:219)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:307)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:301)
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:197)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:188)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:129)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:750)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:622)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:475)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:542)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:106)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at rwb.run(Unknown Source:69)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
2020-08-31 13:49:19.427 6322-6346/? E/FA-SVC: Failed to get app instance id. appId: com.google.android.apps.messaging, java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
2020-08-31 13:49:20.293 6322-6336/? E/FA-SVC: Failed to get app instance id. appId: com.google.android.apps.messaging, java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

I added google-service.json, i also added dependencies:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }


}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also dependencies:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
        buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
    
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
    
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
        implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    
        //Butterknife
        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.1'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
    
        //dexter permissions
        implementation "com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0"
    
        // circular imageview
        implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.0.1'
    
        //Glide
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.10.0'
        implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.0.0') {
            exclude group: 'glide-parent'
        }
        annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    
        implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'
    
        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
    
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
    
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

ProfileActivity for the user profile photos:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.anisacoding.shag2.Home.MainActivity;
import com.anisacoding.shag2.R;
import com.anisacoding.shag2.SignInActivity;
import com.anisacoding.shag2.Utils.BottomNavigationViewHelper;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;


/**
 * Created by User on 5/28/2017.
 */




public class ProfileActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "ProfileActivity";
    private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 4;

    Context mContext = com.anisacoding.shag2.Profile.ProfileActivity.this;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    protected void onCreate(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate: starting.");
        mProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.profileProgressBar);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        setupBottomNavigationView();
        setupToolbar();
    }






        /**
         * Responsible for setting up the profile toolbar
         */
        private void setupToolbar() {
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.profileToolBar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            ImageView menu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu);
            menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to account settings.");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AccountSettingsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }


        public void setupBottomNavigationView(){
            Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
            BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
            BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
            BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(mContext, bottomNavigationViewEx);
            Menu menu = bottomNavigationViewEx.getMenu();
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
        }




    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private TextView profileNameTextView, profileSurnameTextView, profilePhonenoTextView;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private ImageView profilePicImageView;
    private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    private TextView textViewemailname;
    private EditText editTextName;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        editTextName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        profilePicImageView = findViewById(R.id.profile_photo);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
        StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference();
        // Get the image stored on Firebase via "User id/Images/Profile Pic.jpg".
        storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Images").child("Profile Pic").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                // Using "Picasso" (http://square.github.io/picasso/) after adding the dependency in the Gradle.
                // ".fit().centerInside()" fits the entire image into the specified area.
                // Finally, add "READ" and "WRITE" external storage permissions in the Manifest.
                Picasso.get().load(uri).fit().centerInside().into(profilePicImageView);
            }
        });
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignInActivity.class));
        }
        final FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                UserInformation userProfile = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
                profileNameTextView.setText(userProfile.getUserName());
                profileSurnameTextView.setText(userProfile.getdisplay_description());
                profilePhonenoTextView.setText(userProfile.getUserPhone());
                textViewemailname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Email);
                textViewemailname.setText(user.getEmail());
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled( DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, databaseError.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    public void buttonClickedEditName(View view) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View alertLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editprofile, null);
        final EditText etUsername = alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.username);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Name Edit");
        // this is set the view from XML inside AlertDialog
        alert.setView(alertLayout);
        // disallow cancel of AlertDialog on click of back button and outside touch
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String name = etUsername.getText().toString();
                String surname = profileSurnameTextView.getText().toString();
                String phone =  profilePhonenoTextView.getText().toString();
                UserInformation userinformation = new UserInformation();
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userinformation);
                databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userinformation);
                etUsername.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
    public void buttonClickedEditSurname(View view) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View alertLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editprofile, null);
        final EditText etUserSurname = alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.display_description);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Surname Edit");
        // this is set the view from XML inside AlertDialog
        alert.setView(alertLayout);
        // disallow cancel of AlertDialog on click of back button and outside touch
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                String name = profileNameTextView.getText().toString();
                String surname = etUserSurname.getText().toString();
                String phone =  profilePhonenoTextView.getText().toString();
                UserInformation userinformation = new UserInformation();
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userinformation);
                databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userinformation);
                etUserSurname.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
    public void buttonClickedEditPhoneNo(View view) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View alertLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editprofile, null);
        final EditText etUserPhoneno = alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.PhoneNumber);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Phone No Edit");
        // this is set the view from XML inside AlertDialog
        alert.setView(alertLayout);
        // disallow cancel of AlertDialog on click of back button and outside touch
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String name = profileNameTextView.getText().toString();
                String surname = profileSurnameTextView.getText().toString();
                String phone =  etUserPhoneno.getText().toString();
                UserInformation userinformation = new UserInformation();
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userinformation);
                databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userinformation);
                etUserPhoneno.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    public void navigateLogOut(View v){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        Intent inent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(inent);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add the code where you are making the request?

Comment: The firebase?  i only added it  following this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: I will add the profileActivity and other activities related too in the question. Do i need to code in the activities to add firebase?

Comment: no that will be fine I'll just check if there is any bug in the code. if the cod is fine then I might ask you to add the firebase and give me the sample code

Comment: I cant add all the code of the activities because of the limit. But i could only add one Activity: profileActivity.

Comment: thats fine @Ani :)